# What happens to EX if E|X| is infinity?

Tags: probability, expected-value, absolute-value, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

---------original question----------------

According to my professor, we can divide $X$ into $X_+=\max(X,0)$ and $X_-=-\min(X,0)$, both nonnegative.

And we have $EX=EX_+-EX_-$ and $E|X|=EX_++EX_-$

For $E\{X_+\}$ finite and $E\{X_-\}$ finite, we have both $E\{X\}$ and $E\{|X|\}$ finite.
If only of $E\{X_+\}$ and $E\{X_-\}$ is finite and the other one is infinite, then both of $E\{X\}$ and $E\{|X|\}$ are infinite.

However, for both $E\{X_+\}$ and $E\{X_-\}$ being infinite, $E\{X\}$ doesn't exist.

My quesition is: Why $E\{X\}$ doesn't exist for the last case? Can't it be a finite number? Could you prove this? If it's wrong, could you find a counterexample?

Thanks!

------------------update-------------

Thanks for the comments! How about this question, can $EX$ be finite when $E|X|$ is infinite? How to prove or give a counterexample?

Comment: You can't prove and can't give a counterexample. This is just a definition. There is no right or wrong here. The definition says that if both $\mathbb{E}[X_+]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_-]$ are infinite then the expectation of $X$ is undefined.

Comment: You said yourself, $EX = EX_+ - EX_-$. If both are infinite, then what is the result supposed to be..?

Comment: @AlvinL Thanks a lot! I get it. How about the changed question?

Comment: @Mark Thank you! Could you give some advice on the changed question?

Comment: What is $EX$ if $X$ is not integrable in the first place?

Comment: @XiangyuCui As you wrote yourself, if $\mathbb{E}|X|$ is infinite then one of $\mathbb{E}[X_+]$ or $\mathbb{E}[X_-]$ is infinite, and in this case the expectation of $X$ is either infinite or undefined. So no, it can't be finite in this case.

Comment: @mark
Do you mean $\infty-\infty$ is undefined? 
Can I say we don't define $EX$ if E|X| is infinite?

Comment: @Alvin
Thank you! Could you give me an example? Why can we say $X$ is not integrable if $E|X| $is infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just one of those things and not particular to probability.  Consider $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{x}$.  This function is not integrable, but there are various ways to get finite numbers out of it, e.g.
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x}+\int_{-1/\epsilon}^{-\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x}\right)=0.
$$
Or consider that a conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to sum to any real number, e.g.
$$
\sum_n\frac{1}{2n}=\infty, \quad\sum_n\frac{1}{2n+1}=\infty,\quad \sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\log2.
$$

More generally, there's a whole industry of getting finite answers from divergent phenomenon.  The definition of $L^1$ is the "unambiguous" case where there's really only one way to make sense of the thing.

By $L^1$ or integrable I mean $\int|f|<\infty$.  In other words $\int f_+$ and $\int f_-$ are both finite using your notation.  If exactly one of them is infinite, you might assign $\pm\infty$ to the result without ambiguity, but $\infty-\infty$ doesn't make unambiguous sense; you would need some way to interpret it like the examples above.

Comment: Thank you!

Could you explain what do you mean by "The definition of L1
 is the "unambiguous" case where there's really only one way to make sense of the thing."?

I don't know what's $L^1$. 

Did you refer to the way of defining "doesn't exist" by saying "one way to make sense of the thing"?